# Finding Child Elements Using Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have placed the ListView inside Panel. The Listview contains CheckBoxes. Now, if I click on the panel, it should only display Popup, when the checkBOX is checked. Otherwise It should not load Popup.

Now how to check using the jQuery whether the Checkbox inside Listview is checked or not? Please Help....

```
 if ($('#<%=ListView.ClientID%> input:checkbox).is(:checked)')){ShowLoadingPanel();}





<telerik:RadListView ID="Listview" runat="server" OnItemCommand="Listview_ItemCommand" 
                                        AllowMultiItemSelection="true">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <telerik:RadButton ID="chk1" ButtonType="ToggleButton" ToggleType="CheckBox"
                                                Text='<%# Eval("c") %>' CssClass="CheckBox" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" 
                                                AutoPostBack="true" ForeColor="Black" Font-Size="12px" line-height="18px">
                                            </telerik:RadButton>
                                            <br />
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </telerik:RadListView>
```

Comment: please show me your code/html

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($(#myListViewID > input[type=checkbox]:checked).length > 0) doPopup();
```

ref: http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/

Answer (score 2):

```
if($('#ListView input:checkbox').is(':checked')){

}
```

Comment: Not working.....if ($('#<%=ListView%> input:checkbox').is(':checked')) {
                        alert("Testing");
                        ShowLoadingPanel();
                       
                    }

Comment: `<%=ListView%>` ? What are you expecting to be in here? Do you mean `<%=ListView.ClientId%>`? This is why we ask for code snippets. Please edit your question to add more information.

Comment: check ur code,
    **if ($('#<%=ListView.ClientID%> input:checkbox').is(':checked)'))**
The quotes are not properly closed.